# can a method get called automatically?

Tags: java

consider the two classes below, why when I call the print method in the second class i get "blueblueblue is blue repeated" instead of "blueblueblue"  despite the fact that tostring() was never called

```
public class Simple{ 
     private String word; 
     private String phrase; 
     public Simple(int number, String w) {  
          word = w;     
          phrase = mystery(number, w);          
     }   
     private String mystery(int num, String s) {    
          String answer = "";   
          for (int k=0; k<num; k++) {       
               answer = answer + s;     
          }     
          return answer; 
     } 

     public String toString() {     
          return phrase + " is " + word + " repeated";
     }
}
```

```java
public class TestSimple{
     public void print() {      
          Simple item = new Simple(3, "blue");      
          System.out.println(item);             
     }      
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why do you expect `"blueblueblue"` to be printed? How do you think `System.out.println` converts your object into a string representation? Are you aware that `toString` is a method inherited from `Object`, which you are overriding?

Answer (score -1):

yeah,the system out finally will invoke the
object's toString method. you can get the source  code.